# Full Information Maximum Likelihood - Under some other name in Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, variable, maximum, missing

I have recently stumbled upon something called FIML - Full Information Maximum Likelihood. Apparently this methodology helps overcome missing variables provided the gaps are random. Searching the documentation and this site I find nothing on this. Perhaps it is under a different name?

Comment: Something like [FindDistributionParameters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistributionParameters.html)?  The first basic example has "Obtain the maximum likelihood parameter estimates...", but not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this could become a good question if further developed. @Rogo, could you please give more background? FIML deals with missing data. Mathematica has an option `MissingDataMethod` but it seems `FindDistributionParameters` doesn't take that option and  I don't see any FIML option anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: A better question would will explain what  FIML is, offer a minimal example dataset with missing values and the result you expect from FIML, for instance, when analyzed with *R*. And show due diligence looking for the closest thing found in the MAthematica documentation.

Comment: I would love to have the time to dig into this. Alas, I do not. An implementation of FIML is reasonably within reach by grouping the data by the missing pattern and making Maximum likelihood estimation for each group, then combining the results.

Comment: This text is older but describes what this is all about [FIMLOF](https://proceedings.systemdynamics.org/1976/proceed/peter841.pdf) coming from dynamical system identification (the _OF_ in FIMLOF is for _optimal filtering_).

Comment: OK, thanks to all for the feedback. I just wanted to make sure it was not already out there before I started working on it. I have some sources to explore to make up an example. More coming...

Comment: @gwr the link won't display. Roots return a message about not getting a secure connection. Any chance of a typo in the link?

Comment: I just checked and it works fine here - browser settings?

Comment: I see that you are also into Bayesian stats a bit from your other posts and I would recommend _"Probabilistic Graphical Models"_ by D. Koller and N. Friedman as it is nicely founded in probability theory and quite generally applicable. EM and Maximum Likelihood with missing data is all in it. (I have not seen this implemented in WL yet, but maybe somebody knows?)

Comment: @gwr This is a really interesting project. I have read the Peterson paper. The Koller and Freedman book is arriving from Amazon next week. I am weak on control theory. Would you have any interest in working on this with me, perhaps outside of this forum as it could get very lengthy?